# Can't read photos from sdcard to upload to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: android, azure-storage

I'm using Azure Storage SDK to upload images from the devices sdcard or camera app, however I'm getting a FileNotFoundException even for a Uri returned from the gallery app.

Here is my code:

```
 private String uploadImage(CloudBlobContainer container, Uri photoUri) throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, IOException {
        String filename = FileUtilities.getFilenameFromUri(mContext, photoUri);
        // Upload an image file.
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(filename);
        blob.uploadFromFile(photoUri.getPath());

        return filename;
    }
```

photoUri value: content://media/external/images/media/3617
filename value: 20141012_084042.jpg

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: A Uri does not necessarily point to a literal file system file.  Yours is an example of one that does not (yes, there is a file on the card, but your android version appears to be one which only permits indirect access).

Comment: I'm using the same Uri to load images into an ImageView using Picasso and it works fine. Why it won't work only with this code?

Comment: You are presumably accessing as a URI and not as a File in the working case.

Comment: How can I make it work then?

Comment: Find a different upload method in this sdk which can take a uri, or raw data and read from it yourself.  At an extreme, read from the uri into a temporary file and upload that (but that would be a very ugly method).

Comment: The Azure Storage Android SDK has an upload method which takes an InputStream and the stream length. If you can get a FileInputStream (perhaps using openFileInput) which reads from the file, you can use that to upload the blob.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the SDK only has methods to upload using path as a string or URI, and using a InputStream, however, the code to get a InputStream doesn't work.

Comment: If it's really that broken and doesn't accept a Uri (rather than a path) you'll have to copy the data to a literal File.  But the InputStream method is likely to work if correctly used.

Comment: I've used this way: 
File file = new File(photoUri.toString());
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);